# Firefox Appends .sql to Javascript Blob File

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, blob

I'm using code similar to:

```
var saveData = (function () {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";
    return function (data, fileName) {
        var json = JSON.stringify(data),
            blob = new Blob([json], {type: "text/plain"}),
            url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        a.href = url;
        a.download = fileName;
        a.click();
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    };
}());

var data = { x: 42, s: "hello, world", d: new Date() },
    fileName = "my-download.geojson";

saveData(data, fileName);
```

to save a geojson object that my mapping application is building. When I save the file in Firefox it automatically appends a .sql extension to the filename.

So instead of seeing "my-download.geojson", I am getting "my-download.geojson.sql"

Has anyone else experienced this problem? How would one go about fixing it? It works fine in chrome.

Comment: that should not be. check your addons.

Comment: @dandavis Should I be looking for one in particular?